# Does the high-level consumer exploit the new offset management in Kafka 0.8.2?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In 0.8.2, it seems like committing offsets no longer has the same performance problems that it used to (http://blog.confluent.io/2014/12/02/whats-coming-in-apache-kafka-0-8-2/). Does the high level consumer also exploit this, or is it a separate API? I.e. can I safely start committing much more often when using the high-level consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't yet speak to the performance comparison with the Zookeeper offset storage, but the high level consumer does support storing offsets in Kafka with 0.8.2.  You can configure it by setting the property `offsets.storage` to `kafka`.  You will also want to set the property `dual.commit.enabled` to `true` during the migration process for any existing consumer groups currently committing offsets to Zookeeper.

See the Apache Kafka FAQ for [details on migration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdowemigratetocommittingoffsetstoKafka(ratherthanZookeeper)in0.8.2?).